# Create simple form that redirects to a webpage

Tags: html, forms, redirect

Long and short, I had a form input button on my site that worked as an access code to redirect to a specific page on the site. Site broke, and now I don't remember the code I had in place. It was done a long time ago and I only had to do it once. But the gist of it looks like this:

For example the address to site is `www.brokensite.com`. I had a form input field on the page where the value of the input field when submitted redirected to the page `www.brokensite.com/inputvalue`. So if I input the access code of `helpme`, it would redirect to `www.brokensite.com/helpme`

My current code is:

```html
<form action="/after-school-registration/" method="$_GET" name="access">
    <input name="code" value="" type="Text"> 
    <input value="Go" type="Submit">
</form>
```

Please tell me what I am missing. Or what I did wrong this time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$_GET` is not a method

Comment: Why don't you just provide links like website are supposed to have?

Comment: It is for an elementary school and they want a level of privacy of the content on the page for each school. To resolve that. We give them an access code that redirects to their special page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript and set the location:

```
<form>
    <input id='urlpage' />
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/after-school-registration/' + document.getElementById('urlpage').value">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Steve, you are a life saver! Does just what I needed. Thank You so much!